# KOMA book TOC styling at subsection level

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

Here is the very minimal example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrbook}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}

\end{document}
```

Here is the resulting TOC, and my question:

[image: TOC page from the MWE]

It is the space between the subsection number and the subsection title that I want to be able to adjust. So, how to do? If I have overlooked something the the KOMA-script documentation (I have the 2022-10-12 version), a pointer there would also be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the width reserved for the number, e.g., using `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry` with option `numwidth`:

```
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[numwidth=2em]{section}{subsection}
```

You can also change the indent of the entry or use an automatic width calculation (with current `numwidth` value as minimum width). See section 15.3 and table 15.1 of the KOMA-Script manual (available in English and German) for more information.

Alternatively you can use a `\RedeclareSectionCommand` to also change ToC entry options. In this case you have to prepend the option with `toc` or `tocentry`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrbook}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocentrynumwidth=2em]{subsection}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image: reduced number width]

See also: “[How to adjust the indents in the table of contents to the actual width of the numbers](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/HowTo_ToCDynNumWidthIndent/)” or „[Wie die Einzüge im Inhaltsverzeichnis an die tatsächliche Breite der Nummern anpassen werden können](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-de/HowTo_ToCDynNumWidthIndent/)”.